# Postman Transfer start delay

Tags: php, laravel, api, postman

I'm having an issue with an API request which takes more than 7 minutes to return a response. The delay occurs from the application itself or using the browser. Using Postman, 7m 8.04s out of a total of 7m 8.28s goes to the Transfer start, with a total size of 246.03 KB.

The server is running on AWS link to an RDS database both hosted on Amazon. All other API calls work properly.

As I have read, when the transfer start has a delay, usually the issue is from the code (execution time of the code on the server), however when i run the same code on my localhost this issue disappears

From where do you suggest that I should start troubleshooting?

The php code running is shown below:

```
public function getCategories()
{

    $cats = \App\Models\Categories::where('name', '!=', '')->where('parent_id', '0')->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get();

    $i = 0;
    if (count($cats) > 0) {
        foreach ($cats as $p_cat) {
            $cats[$i]->sub = UserController::sub_categories($p_cat->id);
            $cats[$i]->icon = URL::to('/categories/' . $p_cat->icon);
            $cats[$i]->image = URL::to('/categories/' . $p_cat->image);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return response(['success' => 1, 'statuscode' => 200, 'msg' => __('msg.cat_with_sub_cat'), 'data' => $cats], 200);
}

public static function sub_categories($id)
{

    $cats = \App\Models\Categories::where('name', '!=', '')->where('parent_id', $id)->orderBy('name')->get();

    $i = 0;
    if (count($cats) > 0) {
        foreach ($cats as $p_cat) {
            $cats[$i]->sub = UserController::sub_categories($p_cat->id);
            $cats[$i]->icon = URL::to('/categories/' . $p_cat->icon);
            $cats[$i]->image = URL::to('/categories/' . $p_cat->image);
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $cats;
}
```

Comment: How much rows (cats) do you have in your production database? And how much in your local database?

Comment: @fff both are the same, i have two test environments one local and one on the test server

Comment: You should use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php to check your code fragments execution time. I haven’t used AWS yet, but if I’m not mistaken, you can specify which region the server and database should be in. If they are not in the same region, it can cause a long response time.

Comment: @fff This was the issue - the server was hosted in a region whereas the database was hosted in another region causing this 7 minutes delay.. I tested it directly on the production server (same region) and it took less than a second. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome :)